# How to use WebSockets with Play Framework?

Tags: java, javascript, playframework, websocket

I have downloaded Play Framework from GitHub and compiled it. Now I want to use WebSockets and made a JavaScript client and a WebSocket controller similar to the one on [Using WebSockets](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/asynchronous#UsingWebSockets), but it doesn't work. I can open the WebSocket, but the controller doesn't receive any message I send to it. And I can't close the WebSocket with `ws.close();`, but if I update my webpage in the browser, the WebSocket is closed on the server.

How can I receive and send WebSocket messages using Play Framework?

Here is my Play Framework WebSocketController:

```
public class TestSocket extends WebSocketController {

    public static void hello(String name) {

        while(inbound.isOpen()) {
            WebSocketEvent evt = await(inbound.nextEvent());
            if(evt instanceof WebSocketFrame) {
                WebSocketFrame frame = (WebSocketFrame)evt;
                System.out.println("received: " + frame.getTextData());
                if(!frame.isBinary()) {
                    if(frame.getTextData().equals("quit")) {
                        outbound.send("Bye!");
                        disconnect();
                    } else {
                        outbound.send("Echo: %s", frame.getTextData());
                    }
                }
            } else if(evt instanceof WebSocketClose) {
                System.out.println("socket closed");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my JavaScript client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>WebSocket test</title>
<style>
.message {background: lightgray;}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('sendbutton')
        .addEventListener('click', sendMessage, false);
    document.getElementById('connectbutton')
        .addEventListener('click', connect, false);
    document.getElementById('disconnectbutton')
        .addEventListener('click', disconnect, false);
}

function writeStatus(message) {
    var html = document.createElement("div");
    html.setAttribute('class', 'message');
    html.innerHTML = message;
    document.getElementById("status").appendChild(html);
}

function connect() {
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000/ws?name=TestUser");

    ws.onopen = function(evt) { 
        writeStatus("connected");
    }

    ws.onclose = function(evt) {
        writeStatus("disconnected");
    }

    ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
        writeStatus("response: " + evt.data);
    }

    ws.onerror = function(evt) {
        writeStatus("error: " + evt.data);
    }
}

function disconnect() {
    ws.close();
}

function sendMessage() {
    ws.send(document.getElementById('messagefield').value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>WebSocket test</h1>
<button id="connectbutton">Connect</button>
<button id="disconnectbutton">Disconnect</button><br>
<input type="text" id="messagefield"/><button id="sendbutton">Send</button>
<div id="status"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have taken your code and run it on Chrome 14 and 15 and Firefox 7, with the latest version of Play from the Master Branch, and it seems to work mostly. I can

- connect
- send message

The changes I made where

- define `ws` at a global scope, so put `var ws = null` just before the window.onload function.
- for Firefox, I had to use `MozWebSocket` instead of `WebSocket`, so you may need to put an if statement to check based on browser.
- change `frame.getTextData()` to `frame.textData`
- `frame.isBinary()` to `frame.isBinary`

The second two bullets I had to do to get the code to compile?!

Comment: But I did download it from GitHub, see my first sentence.

Comment: Hmmm, Nicolas has mentioned this to be fixed. Maybe this is not the problem. Unfortunately, I am on a later version of Chome & FF, so cannot test either.

Comment: The simple example with `outbound.send("Hello %s!", name);` works fine.

Comment: For me, it doesn't compile with `frame.textData` and `frame.isBinary`, it only compiles with `frame.getTextData()` and `frame.isBinary()`. `"Error raised is : isBinary cannot be resolved or is not a field"`

Comment: It sounds like we don't use the same source code, I downloaded my code today with `git clone git://github.com/playframework/play.git --depth 1` and compiled it using `ant` in the `framework/` folder.

Comment: What platform are you on? I have now tried on Mac OS X, and it works as you described. But now when I try on Windows again, I get the same problem as before.

Comment: I have found the error, on Windows the `import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.websocket.WebSocketFrame;` was imported but on Mac `play.mvc.Http.WebSocketFrame;` was imported which is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the above code on Chrome 20 and Play 1.2.4

Upgraded to Play 1.2.5 and works like a charm!!